# Stop very long running delayed jobs

Tags: ruby, delayed-job

I have some jobs which take very-very long time to finish. Usually 1-3 hours.
I use the gem "daemons" to daemonize the delayed workers.
If I use the rake task: "script/delayed_job stop" to stop them, then they won't stop until the
workers finish...

Is there a nice and simple solution to stop the jobs?

I have managed to do one, but any other suggestions are also welcome.

The idea is to:

- trap the "TERM" signal (because daemons sends "TERM" for its spawned processes) and save the old
- when the "TERM" signal comes, then finish the job (but don't yet quit)
- after terminating the job setting back the old handler for "TERM"
- sending the "TERM" to the process I am in (The old handler will be called)

Here is the code:

```
def self.prepare_to_be_stopped_by_daemons
  self.old_trap = Signal.trap("TERM") do
    self.should_terminate = true
  end
end
def check_the_stop_signal_by_daemons
  if self.class.should_terminate
    Delayed::Worker.logger.debug "Asked to be TERMINATED. Calling the old trap." if Delayed::Worker.logger
    self.class.restore_old_trap
    Process.kill("TERM", Process.pid)

    raise StopCrawlingException.new
  end
end

def self.restore_old_trap
  Signal.trap("TERM", old_trap)
end
```